# Xcode 13.2.1 Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code Error

Tags: xcode, xcode13

I am trying to generate archive of my project but I am getting the above error. I have already checked the similar problems and made changes but it wasn't solve the problem. I have got successful build on similator.

Since my mac is old I am unable to get latest Xcode relase. That's why I have Xcode 13.2.1

The Error is:

```
PhaseScriptExecution [CP]\ Embed\ Pods\ Frameworks /Users/selsa/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gvvqzxpfetwxdobvettmuxwhyjau/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/Script-CD8053175E8846FE90FD427D.sh (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')

mkdir -p /Users/selsa/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gvvqzxpfetwxdobvettmuxwhyjau/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/Runner.app/Frameworks
Symlinked...
readlink: illegal option -- f
usage: readlink [-n] [file ...]
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

My Podfile is:

```
platform :ios, '12.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
  installer.generated_projects.each do |project|
    project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '12.0'
         end
    end
  end
end
```

Runner Configuration:

I edited the Runner Configirations as shown in Screen Shot of Xcode

[Xcode Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRoeD.jpg)

I did edit the *frameworks.sh * and add

```
if [ -L "${source}" ]; then
    echo "Symlinked..."
    source="$(readlink -f "${source}")"
  fi
```

I have changed the pod file the below code

From

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

To

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
  installer.generated_projects.each do |project|
    project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '12.0'
         end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: The error seems clear. `readlink` doesn't like the `-f` option. You should remove that option.

Comment: @HangarRash Actually it was originally has not -f option I have added it after reading some suggestion but I will try it again removing it.

Comment: Most suggestions to add `-f` were due to a change in Xcode 14.3. You seem to be using Xcode 13.2.1.